# Disable date range swipe left/right action with two fingers in stock charts

Tags: anychart

Has anyone found a way to disable the swipe right/left action with two fingers when you're visualizing a specific date range of your stock chart? I've implemented my own zoom-in/out feature and it's currently conflicting with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current version of the library (8.9.0) doesn't provide a possibility to disable this interactivity. We will take it into account for future updates.

Comment: It'd be great if we could disable this, because the 1 finger swipe behaves exactly the same with 2 fingers, which directly conflicts with any zoom in/out solution.